# how can I fetch random rows from a table in the database

Tags: php, sql

Please can anyone be of help, I was trying to design a computer based test with php and database but have problem with random fetching of questions from the database

Comment: I would generate a random(ish) number between 1 and total row count and query where the row ID is that number...

Comment: Hi Emmanuel and welcome to SO (StackOverflow). I see you have recently joined us. We strive to be a wonderful community and provide people with solutions to their coding problems as best we can. There are some basic fundamentals to [asking a good question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consequently getting more experienced users to help you. In addition, most of us would like to see that you have put some effort into solving your problem. Show us what you've tried and what the results were. Again, welcome to SO!

Comment: not with my system now just got a friend system to get the question online

Comment: alright  Kuya thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()
```

With limit

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

> You select random records using RAND function

Comment: alright thanks @ Rahautos but can I use limit with it as well

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1 @Emmanuel

Comment: Plz accept my answer if its work :) thanks @Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY RAND() is useful if you are returning a small set of results.  If however the result set is large (you have thousands of questions), it's possible to fetch them into an array:

```
SELECT question FROM quiztable WHERE questionID=?;
```

Then after that, use:

```
 array_rand($resultset)
```

This gets a random question from the $resultset query.